# Best Practice to share spring boot repositories and DTO

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, architecture

I have two maven projects sharing the same module that contain repositories, DTOs :

- **Project1:**

  -------->module1

  -------->module2

  -------->shared module

  -------->pom.xml
- **Project2:**

  -------->module3

  -------->module4

  -------->shared module

  -------->pom.xml

What is the best way to avoid duplication ?

Comment: What are you calling "duplication" here ?

Comment: Make a separate micro-service for repositories? Make a library, push it to local/internal artifactory and use it as dependency?

Comment: @Arnaud,Duplication of DTO's and repositories in the module 'shared module'

Comment: @uneq95, micro-service for repositories ? there is no servies rest for this module only repositories and DTOs ? can you detail this point?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java code that is needed in two multi-module projects, use a separate project and use Maven dependencies.

I don't understand how repositories can be a part of a multi-module project.

Answer (score 0):

Repositories are responsible for interacting with your database. Instead of replicating the same code in multiple micro services, you could build one micro service which handles all your database related stuff and have your other micro services call it for any kind of database related query.

Different DTOs could also be reused if you just build a separate library containing all the DTOs and publish them on an internal maven repository, for instance, and your other micro services could just add this library as dependency and use them.

PS: I would like to encourage experts to comment on it , if its a good/bad approach. This is what I know with the meagre amount of experience I have in the industry.